# Execute php script on server every 5 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want to run a php script every 5 minutes that processes some simple mysql queries to identify potential errors and in case an error is recorded as a database entry the php script sends out an email.

From my research, it seems like cron jobs (or task schedulers) usually take care of running scripts at specified times, however I cannot find this option anywhere at the hosting service I am using (who runs "Parallels Plesk Panel 11.0.9" as the management interface I can access).

Therefore I tried the following "trick":

```
<?php
$active = $_GET["a"];
set_time_limit(0);
while($active == 1){
    include 'alert_exe.php';
    sleep(300); // execute script every 5 mins
}
?>
```

To active the script I enter the url (".../alert.php?a=1"). This works fine for a couple of minutes, however it seems after 2 or 3 minutes the script stops executing.

Any idea how I can prevent the stopping of the script or alternative suggestions how to achieve the automatic execution of a script every 5minutes (without being able to access cron jobs)?

Thanks!

Comment: The host you are running on has surely configured a time-out for long-running scripts to protect it from getting overloaded.

Comment: Take a look at your hosting solution specification. Some do not allow use of crons, especially the free ones. There are however a few that allow crons. Your best solution may be to simply find a host that supports crons,  which is what I did when I had this issue. Similarly, the host may be preventing your script from running.

Comment: If you are on a shared hosting there's no way. Script executed from the browser follow php.ini execution time limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would not surprise me that a hosting service would protect its servers from getting overloaded with long-running scripts, and would configure a time-out after which such scripts are aborted (see [PHP: Runtime Configuration Settings](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) and **max_execution_time** in particular).

If you have a PC that can stay turned on, an alternative solution would be to let it send a request to the server every 5 minutes:

```
<?php
    // Your PHP code that has to be executed every 5 minutes comes here
?>
<script>
setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 5*60*1000);
// just show current time stamp to see time of last refresh.
document.write(new Date());
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions - works like a charm and I have a spare PC to do the job!

Comment: If you don't have a spare PC lying around, another way to accomplish this is to have a free site like https://uptimerobot.com ping the script for you every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `max_execution_time` parameter which stops the script if it takes too long, 30 seconds by default, see the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time.

You can try to do `set_time_limit(0)` at the beginning of your script (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), or change the `max_execution_time` parameter itself.

But in general, I would not go with such solution, it is not very reliable. Better find a hosting where you can use `cron` or you can try to look for some external service which will ping your script every 5 minutes (probably you can use services which monitor the web application health).

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
<?php
$interval=5; //minutes
set_time_limit(0);
while (true)
{
$now=time();
include("alert_exe.php");
sleep($interval*05-(time()-$now));
}
?>
```

Stop the script by restarting apache, or build in a return value from your internal script which changes while (true) to while (false)